# Should we create [cloudsponge] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

My reputation is not high enough yet;strong text can someone please help me by creating the [cloudsponge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudsponge) tag?

Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.

There are [some existing questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cloudsponge) that people have already asked about CloudSponge. Here are a few highlights:

- [Cloudsponge asynchronous javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151530/cloudsponge-asynchronous-javascript)
- [How does CloudSponge import your iCloud contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029849/how-does-cloudsponge-import-your-icloud-contacts)
- [Bootstrap tags input with CloudSponge - how to add tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391125/bootstrap-tags-input-with-cloudsponge-how-to-add-tag)

I'd like to see a [cloudsponge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudsponge) tag so that:

- developers would be able to easily find answered questions,
- developers would be able to tag new questions and
- the CloudSponge support team (including me) would be able to more easily monitor and answer new questions about our product on SO.

Additionally, there is already a community of active developers using CloudSponge and it would be great to see more of it happening on SO.

Excerpt:

> A question about the CloudSponge product or how to integrate with it.

Wiki:

> This tag is used to identify questions about the CloudSponge product or specific integration or customization questions.
>
> If you have a question about integration or customizations, please check the [documentation](https://www.cloudsponge.com/developer/getting-started/) and [examples](https://www.cloudsponge.com/address-book-widget/examples/) first. If you still have a question, go ahead and post it with this tag.

Comment: I've suggested an edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151530/cloudsponge-asynchronous-javascript) to add the [cloud-sponge] tag. The tag will be created if the edit is approved.

Comment: Consider adding more information to the Excerpt and Wiki for users who do not know what cloudsponge is.